# matrix computation from XML values

Tags: java, xml

good day everyone. i try learn some about parsing files, and i decide start with DOM, xPath or SAX, 
  for example how can i getting numeric values form two 2x2 matrix.

and afterwards perform computation  in JAVA of these two matrix to output result. 
what is best to use for parsing,and then obtain result for computation matrixes with some algorithm?

Comment: You've provided very little information here. Please provide some examples of your inputs and desired output. Also, show us what you've done so far? I imagine Google has already given you some good ideas of how to parse XML.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the [`JScience`](http://jscience.org/) library, which uses [*javolution*](http://javolution.org/) for [XML marshaling](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/xml/package-summary.html#package_description).